# Is it possible to add a Windows service dependency using powershell?

Tags: powershell, service

I know there is this [sc.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sc.mspx?mfr=true) where you can add and set Windows service dependencies, but I was wondering if the same thing can be done using Powershell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation: not through the [`Set-Service`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113399) cmdlet.

However the [`Change`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384901%28VS.85%29.aspx) method of [`Win32_Service`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418%28VS.85%29.aspx) allows dependencies to be specified: so WMI can do it.

Comment: Ok. I've never scripted through WMI before. But if powershell can't do it, then I guess I'm left with either sc.exe or WMI.

Comment: You can do the WMI stuff via Powershell.

Comment: example command here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/315616

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible by using `Set-ItemProperty`

```
Set-ItemProperty 
  -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\IBM Cognos" 
  -Name DependOnService 
  -Value @("MSSQLSERVER","W3SVC")
```

If the property did not exist before, you would have to use:

```
New-ItemProperty 
  -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\IBM Cognos" 
  -Name DependOnService 
  -PropertyType MultiString
  -Value @("MSSQLSERVER","W3SVC")
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

No it is definitely possible, see [`DependsOn` parameter on `New-Service`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849830.aspx)

Comment: Why the down vote on this? It is correct.

Comment: It's correct for new services created by `New-Service`, but not for changing existing services with `Set-Service`.